# How can I use SPSS to calculate the scales PSDI and PST from the SCL-90 symptomatology questionnaire, or what would the code for SPSS be?

Tags: xcode, spss

How can I use SPSS to calculate the scales PSDI and PSt from the SCL-90 symptomatology questionnaire, or what would the code for SPSS be?
The scales PSDI and PSDI mean:
PSDI:
Average psychological distress in relation to the items where psychological distress is present (Positive Symptom Distress Index)
PST:
Number of all items where psychological distress is present (Positive Symptom Total)
with
The global score GSI results from GS by dividing this value by the number of (answered) items of the entire test, i.e. in the rule by ninety:

- GSI = GS ÷ (90).
  The global characteristic value PST is obtained by adding the ten stress tendencies per scale, P1 to P10:
- PST = sum of the stress tendencies P1
  to P10.
  The third global characteristic value PSDI is obtained by dividing the sum GS by the global characteristic value PST:
- PSDI = GS / PST.

SCL Skala PST of T0 (we got T0, T1, T2 and T3:

```
COMPUTE SCL90_T0_PST= 0.
DO REPEAT SCL90_T0=SCL90_T0_1 TO SCL90_T0_90.
   IF SCL90_T0 > 0 SCL90_T0_PST = SCL90_T0_PST + 1.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

COMPUTE SCL90_T0_PSDI=(SUM(SCL90_T0_1 TO SCL90_T0_90) / SCL90_T0_PST).
EXECUTE.

type here